# protobuf-net: Handling nulls in IEnumerable? Via what attributes/settings?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Some sample code below. The interesting/problem case is the Data property in 
Mad. This code blows up (null value in the enumerable). Also, it works if i don't use the static attributes but instead the runtime type model, where i put in member.SupportNull = true for the fields (which is the behaviour i want), so what am i missing in the attributes / settings? Google search seems to indicate this is an open issue with probuf-net? That the same functionality is not available via attributes?

As as aside, if someone could suggest a way - i really love the runtime type model, i want to use that everywhere with a nice compiled model... but with it i lose the object versioning that protocol buffers solves! (via explicit tags). Is there any good way to maintain object version compatibility (simply adding fields) without doing all the static notation with fixed tags?

Basically the key thing with the runtime model is the assignment of tag indices and i can't think of a way of handling versions without explicitly specifying the tag indices via attributes...

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ing))]
public class Eff
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string gg { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ing : Eff
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int zz { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Mad
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IEnumerable<ing> Data { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public ing Single { get; set; }
}
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var obj = new Mad
        {
            Name = "test"
            ,Data = new[] { new ing {gg = "ooga", zz = -101},null,new ing()}
            ,Single = new ing {gg = "abc", zz = -999}
        };

        var m = new MemoryStream();
        Serializer.Serialize(m, obj);
        m.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var copy = Serializer.Deserialize<Mad>(m);
    }
```

Comment: Activating the bat signal for all things protobuf! Come on mgravell!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, it seems unavailable via attributes.

Workaround i'm doing for now - for every single type of interest(including the whole inheritance hierarchy) - add it to the type model yourself (with default handling so that it processes attributes), then call .GetFields() and set .SupportNull = true for each field (or only the relevant one)